# Where can I get SUNWsan package for Solaris?

Tags: solaris

The package is not available in the installation DVD, nor internet (MOS, Google, etc.). Where could I get it?

Answer (score 1):

If you do have support from Oracle for Solaris 8 then you'll have to log a support call with them to request a copy of the "SAN Foundation Kit" aka SFK.

However... Solaris 8? Really? Can you not upgrade to a release that's less than 10 years old? Solaris 11 (and even the Solaris 10 Updates) that you can get from Oracle have muchmuch better FC support than was ever available in Solaris 8 or 9.

Answer (score 0):

I know we downloaded the pkg from Sun for our Solaris 8 systems back in the day.  I'm not sure if they did this, but you could always check the media for a newer update of Solaris 8.  Perhaps you'll find the packages there.

Answer (score -1):

Official statement from Oracle:

> Sun products, patches, updates and firmware are now accessible only
>   through the Oracle Technology Network, Oracle Software Delivery Cloud
>   and My Oracle Support. To learn more, refer to the Sun Download Center
>   Announcement.

Have you that one?

You could borrow similar packages from `OpenSolaris` project, e.g. [here](http://mirror.opencsw.org/opencsw/releases/stable/legacy-2008.08/sparc/5.10/)

Also, of course, please specify your Solaris version and platform.

Comment: I do have support, but Oracle no longer provides this download as it ended support for Solaris 8 long time ago.

Also, it seems to be an official Sun package, which was distributed solely by Sun, not through opensource.

P. S. MOS - My Oracle Support.

Comment: Oh, `Solaris 8` really old stuff, I guess you should to pester MOS with what they did - their `SAN Storage` product. I used `Solaris 10`, so packages from `Open Solaris` really helped me (it's like mirror project for 10).